# Problem on the dimension of a linear space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

Suppose M(m,n) is the vector space which is composed of all $n \times m$ real matrices. Let $F(m,n)$, $n>m$, be the set of all $n \times m$ matrices and, for each element $u \in F(m,n)$, the rank of $u$ is $m$. Note that $F(m,n)$ is a subset in vector space $M(m,n)$. Now we can define a equivalence relation on $F(m,n)$. That is，for $u,v \in F(m,n)$, we say $u\sim v$ if there exists an $m \times m$ invertible matrix $A$ such that $u=vA$. Then, for $u\in F(m,n)$, we define a subset of $F(m,n)$ as follows:
$$
G(u)=\{ v \in F(m,n) : v \sim u \}.
$$ 
Finally, suppose that $\left< G(u) \right>$ is the linear space generated by $G(u)$, that is, $\left< G(u) \right>$ is the intersection of all linear spaces that containing $G(u)$.

**My question is:**

What's the dimension of the vector space $\left< G(u) \right>$ ?

**Supplement:**

It is easy to get an answer for $m=1$. In this case, we have $\dim(\left< G(u) \right>)=1=m$. For $m>1$ and $u_1 \in F(m,n)$, I have found $m$ linearly independent vectors $u_1, \cdots, u_m$ in $G(u_1)$. Hence, the dimension of $\left< G(u) \right>$ is at least $m$.

---

**Edit $1$.**

Inspired by amomin's comments, I have found a way to attack this problem, but not completely. Let $u \in F(m,n)$ and suppose that $u_1, \cdots, u_k$ are $k$ elements in $G(u)$. Then, for $i=1, \cdots, k$, there exist $A_i \in \text{GL}(m)$ such that $u_i = uA_i$. Considering the following equation
$$
\lambda_1 uA_1 + \lambda_2 uA_2 + \cdots + \lambda_k uA_k =0. \tag{1}
$$ 
Easily, $(1)$ can be written as an equivalent form 
$$
u(\lambda_1 A_1 + \lambda_2 A_2 + \cdots + \lambda_k A_k)=0. \tag{2}
$$
Together with the rank $r(u)=m$, we can choose $m$ linearly independent rows in $u$.  Meanwhile, the $m$ row vectors can also form an $m \times m$ invertible matrix $u'$. Hence, by $(2)$ we have 
$$
u'(\lambda_1 A_1 + \lambda_2 A_2 + \cdots + \lambda_k A_k)=0, 
$$
and then
$$
\lambda_1 A_1 + \lambda_2 A_2 + \cdots + \lambda_k A_k =0. 
$$
Hence, if $A_1, \cdots, A_k$ are linearly independent in $\text{GL}(m)$, then we have that $u_1, \cdots, u_k$ are $k$ linearly independent vectors in $G(u)$. More specifically, $r(u_1, \cdots, u_k) \geqslant r(A_1, \cdots, A_k)$. Taking this into consideration, let us suppose that the rank $r(\text{GL}(m))=s$ and choose $s$ linearly independent vectors $A_1, \cdots, A_s$ in $\text{GL}(m)$. Set $u_i = uA_i$, for $i=1, \cdots, s$, then, we get $s$ linearly independent vectors $u_i \in G(u)$. Therefore, we have 
$$
\text{dim}(\left< G(u) \right>) = r(G(u)) \geqslant r(\text{GL}(m)) = s.
$$
Here, I have two questions:

**$1.$** What's the rank of $\text{GL}(m)$ ?

**$2.$** Is this equation $r(G(u)) = r(\text{GL}(m))$ valid ?

Comment: Have you tried for a specific example?  E.g. if u is a block matrix consisting of an identity matrix followed (below) by a zero block?  The action of GL(m) will give you all possible invertible matrices A (followed by a zero block) - does that help?

Comment: @amomin Sorry, I don't know your exactly meaning. Could you explain it a little more specificly?

Comment: I mean, e.g. if m = 2 and n = 3, try the matrix u in F(m,n) with rows (1,0), (0,1), (0,0) - notice how it's an identity matrix followed by a zero matrix below it.  You can generalize this to any m,n.  If you multiply on the right by A in GL(m), this will become the matrix (a11, a12), (a21, a22), (0, 0)... GL(m) is dense in the set of all matrices, so hopefully you can determine what <G(u)> is in this case explicitly, and in particular its dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this equation $r(G(u)) = r(\text{GL}(m))$ valid?

Yes. Let $A_1, \dots, A_s\in \text{GL}(m)$ be such that any element of $\text{GL}(m)$ can be expressed as their linear combination. Let $v=uA\in G(u)$, and let $A=\lambda_1A_1+\dots+\lambda_sA_s$. Then $v = \lambda_1uA_1+\dots+\lambda_suA_s$, i.e., any element of $G(u)$ is a linear combination of $uA_1,\dots,uA_s$. Thus $r(G(u)) \leq r(\text{GL}(m))$; together with the opposite inequality, it means that these two values are equal.

> What's the rank of $\text{GL}(m)$?

It's $m^2$. Let $E^{i,j}$, where $1\leq i,j\leq m$, be $m\times m$ matrix with $1$ at the position $(i,j)$ and $0$ at all other positions, and let $I$ be the unit $m\times m$ matrix. Then $I\in\text{GL}(m)$, and for any $i,j$ $I+E^{i,j}\in\text{GL}(m)$, so $E^{i,j}\in\left<\text{GL}(m)\right>$, and the matrices $E^{i,j}$ span the whole $M(m,m)$.